# How should I go about using $graphLookup for Mongo Sample Companies Database

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have been tasked with utilising the $graphLookup function for the sample companies database that MongoDB provides.

I am just having a really hard time figuring out where this function would be applicable with this database. I am aware that I need to utilise a hierarchical data scheme with this function, I am just having a hard time finding where this applies here. An example of the schema is below(sorry it's quite large).

Any help would be much appreciated.

```html
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "52cdef7c4bab8bd675297d98"
    },
    "name": "Slacker",
    "permalink": "slacker",
    "crunchbase_url": "http://www.crunchbase.com/company/slacker",
    "homepage_url": "http://www.slacker.com",
    "blog_url": "",
    "blog_feed_url": "",
    "twitter_username": "SlackerRadio",
    "category_code": "music",
    "number_of_employees": null,
    "founded_year": 2006,
    "founded_month": null,
    "founded_day": null,
    "deadpooled_year": null,
    "deadpooled_month": null,
    "deadpooled_day": null,
    "deadpooled_url": null,
    "tag_list": "",
    "alias_list": "",
    "email_address": "support@slacker.com",
    "phone_number": "",
    "description": "Music Personalization Suite",
    "created_at": "Mon Jun 04 08:45:22 UTC 2007",
    "updated_at": "Sun Mar 17 08:05:45 UTC 2013",
    "overview": "<p>Slacker is the most complete music service on Earth.  The company delivers free and subscription-based access to millions of songs and hundreds of expert-programmed stations, plus news, sports and talk, on the web, mobile devices, in-car infotainment systems and consumer electronics platforms.  By blending cutting-edge analytics with a team of expert music curators and content programmers, Slacker delivers a seamless music discovery experience and uniquely personalized entertainment.  Slacker was founded in 2006 and is headquartered in San Diego with offices in Palo Alto, CA and New York City.  For more information about Slacker, or to listen for free, visit www.slacker.com</p>",
    "image": {
        "available_sizes": [
            [
                [150, 61], "assets/images/resized/0001/7589/17589v4-max-150x150.jpg"
            ],
            [
                [250, 101], "assets/images/resized/0001/7589/17589v4-max-250x250.jpg"
            ],
            [
                [450, 183], "assets/images/resized/0001/7589/17589v4-max-450x450.jpg"
            ]
        ],
        "attribution": null
    },
    "products": [{
        "name": "Slacker Web Player",
        "permalink": "slacker-web-player"
    }, {
        "name": "Slacker Desktop Radio",
        "permalink": "slacker-desktop-radio"
    }, {
        "name": "Slacker Portable Player",
        "permalink": "slacker-portable-player"
    }],
    "relationships": [{
        "is_past": false,
        "title": "President & CEO",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Jim",
            "last_name": "Cady",
            "permalink": "jim-cady"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": false,
        "title": "CRO",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Carter",
            "last_name": "Brokaw",
            "permalink": "carter-brokaw"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": false,
        "title": "CMO",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Craig",
            "last_name": "Rechenmacher",
            "permalink": "craig-rechenmacher"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": false,
        "title": "VP of Engineering",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Brad",
            "last_name": "Kindig",
            "permalink": "brad-kindig"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": false,
        "title": "SVP Strategic Development",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Jack",
            "last_name": "Isquith",
            "permalink": "jack-isquith"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": false,
        "title": "SVP, Sales and Business Development",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Steve",
            "last_name": "Cotter",
            "permalink": "steve-cotter"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": false,
        "title": "Seed Investor (AV)",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Basil",
            "last_name": "Horangic",
            "permalink": "basil-horangic"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": false,
        "title": "CFO",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Beau",
            "last_name": "Paradowsky",
            "permalink": "beau-paradowsky"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": false,
        "title": "Board of Directors",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Mark",
            "last_name": "Leschly",
            "permalink": "mark-leschly"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "CEO",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Dennis",
            "last_name": "Mudd",
            "permalink": "dennis-mudd"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "CFO",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Gary",
            "last_name": "Acord",
            "permalink": "gary-acord"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "SVP Marketing",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Jonathan",
            "last_name": "Sasse",
            "permalink": "jonathan-sasse"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "SVP Product Marketing & Content Programming",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Jonathan",
            "last_name": "Sasse",
            "permalink": "jonathan-sasse"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "Board",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Dennis",
            "last_name": "Mudd",
            "permalink": "dennis-mudd"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "Sr. Account Executive",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Aiko",
            "last_name": "Fujimoto",
            "permalink": "aiko-fuijmoto"
        }
    }, {
        "is_past": true,
        "title": "Chief Revenue Officer",
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Allen",
            "last_name": "Baum",
            "permalink": "allen-baum"
        }
    }],
    "competitions": [{
        "competitor": {
            "name": "Jango",
            "permalink": "jango"
        }
    }, {
        "competitor": {
            "name": "Pandora Media",
            "permalink": "pandora"
        }
    }],
    "providerships": [],
    "total_money_raised": "$73.1M",
    "funding_rounds": [{
        "id": 12,
        "round_code": "b",
        "source_url": "http://www.socaltech.com/slacker_raises_4_m/s-0009377.html",
        "source_description": "",
        "raised_amount": 40000000,
        "raised_currency_code": "USD",
        "funded_year": 2007,
        "funded_month": 6,
        "funded_day": 1,
        "investments": [{
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Centennial Ventures",
                "permalink": "centennial-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Mission Ventures",
                "permalink": "mission-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Sevin Rosen Funds",
                "permalink": "sevin-rosen-funds"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Rho Capital Partners",
                "permalink": "rho-capital-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 13,
        "round_code": "a",
        "source_url": "http://www.techcrunch.com/2007/03/14/new-music-service-slacker-has-very-broad-ambitions/",
        "source_description": "",
        "raised_amount": 13500000,
        "raised_currency_code": "USD",
        "funded_year": 2007,
        "funded_month": 6,
        "funded_day": 1,
        "investments": [{
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Austin Ventures",
                "permalink": "austin-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Mission Ventures",
                "permalink": "mission-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Sevin Rosen Funds",
                "permalink": "sevin-rosen-funds"
            },
            "person": null
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 4968,
        "round_code": "unattributed",
        "source_url": "http://www.paidcontent.org/entry/419-digital-music-service-slacker-gets-5-million-bridge-round/",
        "source_description": "Digital Music Service Slacker Gets $5 Million Bridge Round",
        "raised_amount": 5000000,
        "raised_currency_code": "USD",
        "funded_year": 2009,
        "funded_month": 1,
        "funded_day": 29,
        "investments": [{
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Sevin Rosen Funds",
                "permalink": "sevin-rosen-funds"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Rho Capital Partners",
                "permalink": "rho-capital-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Centennial Ventures",
                "permalink": "centennial-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Mission Ventures",
                "permalink": "mission-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Austin Ventures",
                "permalink": "austin-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 5960,
        "round_code": "d",
        "source_url": "http://www.paidcontent.org/entry/419-radio-player-slacker-raises-10-million/",
        "source_description": "Radio Player Slacker Raises $10 Million In Fourth Round",
        "raised_amount": 9600000,
        "raised_currency_code": "USD",
        "funded_year": 2009,
        "funded_month": 5,
        "funded_day": 14,
        "investments": [{
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Sevin Rosen Funds",
                "permalink": "sevin-rosen-funds"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Rho Capital Partners",
                "permalink": "rho-capital-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Centennial Ventures",
                "permalink": "centennial-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Mission Ventures",
                "permalink": "mission-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }, {
            "company": null,
            "financial_org": {
                "name": "Austin Ventures",
                "permalink": "austin-ventures"
            },
            "person": null
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 11807,
        "round_code": "debt_round",
        "source_url": "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1400813/000140081310000001/xslFormDX01/primary_doc.xml",
        "source_description": "SEC D",
        "raised_amount": 2000000,
        "raised_currency_code": "USD",
        "funded_year": 2010,
        "funded_month": 2,
        "funded_day": 3,
        "investments": []
    }, {
        "id": 21409,
        "round_code": "debt_round",
        "source_url": "http://techcrunch.com/2011/02/10/slacker-raises-3-million-to-equip-more-phones-cars-with-personal-radio-service/",
        "source_description": "Slacker Raises $3 Million To Equip More Phones, Cars With Personal Radio Service",
        "raised_amount": 3000000,
        "raised_currency_code": "USD",
        "funded_year": 2011,
        "funded_month": 2,
        "funded_day": 10,
        "investments": []
    }],
    "investments": [],
    "acquisition": null,
    "acquisitions": [],
    "offices": [{
        "description": "",
        "address1": "16935 W. Bernardo Dr. Suite 101",
        "address2": "",
        "zip_code": "92127",
        "city": "San Diego",
        "state_code": "CA",
        "country_code": "USA",
        "latitude": 33.022176,
        "longitude": -117.081406
    }],
    "milestones": [],
    "ipo": null,
    "video_embeds": [],
    "screenshots": [],
    "external_links": [],
    "partners": []
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you want to use $graphLookup? And I think it would be helpful that if you can provide your expected output and minimize the sample dataset, as you already knew that it is quite big.

Comment: @ray I can't personally identify why I would use $graphLookup and that's what I'm having a difficult time with working out, it is just a task that has been set for me as homework for my course. For the output, I need to limit the search to 20 documents, I haven't been given an output I should be trying to achieve, I just need to provide a scenario where the function would be used for this database and show a query. I will try to minimize the sample as it is pretty hard on the eyes.

Comment: [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) serves the purpose of a recursive search. Without knowing what you want to achieve as the expected outcome, it would be hard for us to comment even whether $graphLookup is the suitable tool. From your description, I think you may start by observing whether there is recusive structure for your sample data, then see how to apply $graphLookup on the structure. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @ray Thanks I will have a closer look at the schema. I had already tried to use $graphLookup to create an array of companies that shared competitors with each company using this DB. I couldn't get this to work though and thought maybe that I cant use $graphLookup on nested documents?